# The correct way to use a for loop in an array C

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I'm having some trouble with a homework assignment dealing with Arrays. I have already read all the text from class (which didn't help me at all), looked up several tutorials on arrays, and searched for similar issues on various sites. Its a simple practice assignment to ease us into the topic but I just can't understand it. I couldn't even get the teachers code to work on Ideone. It came up with a run time error.

The assignment is to create an one dimensional array called InternetHits that holds 10 integer values. Those values are the number of hits a the site receives per day. The user should be able to enter the number of hits.

Here is what I have so far:
It will print the first day the is entered but every day after that is random numbers!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int InternetHits[10];
    int i;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        InternetHits[i];
        printf ("Enter number of hits for day %i\n", i+1);
        scanf ("%i", InternetHits);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf ("Number of hits was %d\n", InternetHits[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: You could start by adding the missing braces around the bodies of your loops.  C++ isn't Python and whitespace doesn't mean a thing.  What you've written there is actually straight C.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser I have broken it down, there are no errors for me to work off of, and I have also tried a few test cases with similar results. The first for loop is printing 10 times like is suppose to and the second for loop is printing but the output numbers are wrong.

Comment: @Blrfl I'll add them now

Comment: @Bill have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: @MichaelT I have not. I was just using Ideone. What do you recommend?

Comment: Downloading an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B), and then stepping through it.  Or learning how to use [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), or [lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org) depending on what you have. But learning how to debug is a *key* skill for programmers.

Comment: Your program is C code, not C++ code. C & C++ are different languages. BTW, if coding in C99 compile with all warnings & debug info, e.g. `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g`, if coding in C++11 compile with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this: `scanf ("%i", InternetHits);` to this: `scanf ("%i",&InternetHits[i]);`

Also, remove this statement `InternetHits[i];` as it has no effect.

Also, change this line

```
  printf ("Number of hits was %d\n", InternetHits[i-1]);
```

to this:

```
  printf ("Number of hits was %d\n", InternetHits[i]);
```

The modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int InternetHits[10];
int i;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

    printf ("Enter number of hits for day %i\n", i+1);
    scanf ("%i", &InternetHits[i]);
}

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf ("Number of hits was %d\n", InternetHits[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: That  worked but now the only problem is that the first output is random numbers. everything after that outputs like it is suppose to.

Comment: @Bill: Did you do all the three changes I mentioned?

Comment: Ah I missed that last one. I was trying to type it out rather than copy and paste. That did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is really a C++ assignment, you will want to use `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`.

I notice you are redeclaring `int i`, so only do that once (e.g. remove the first declaration).

You no longer want to use `printf`, instead use `cout` in the context `cout << "Enter number of hits for day " << i + 1`.

The `for` loop is fine, but instead of using `scanf`, simply do `cin >> InternetHits[i]`.

Similarly for displaying the output, you will want to make use of `cout` and `InternetHits[i]`.

Comment: I removed the `int i` like you said to and it was ok but the other changes caused errors

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf ("%i", InternetHits);
```

should be

```
scanf ("%i", &InternetHits[i]);
```

otherwise only the first position will be overwritten by `scanf()` again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
scanf ("%i", InternetHits);
```

To

```
scanf ("%d", &InternetHits[i]);
```

You need to use `&` while using `scanf` function.

`%d` scans an integer as a signed decimal number,
but `%i` allows defaults to decimal but also allows hexadecimal (if preceded by "0x") and octal if preceded by "0". You can use it as per as your requirement.

in second `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    printf ("Number of hits was %d\n", InternetHits[i-1]);
}
```

while `i=0` , you printing `InternetHits[i-1]` which means `InternetHits[-1]`, which can cause problem.

Answer (score 0):

The program looks like a C program not C++ program

Here is how the program (assuming it is a C program) should look

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int main( void ) 
{
    int InternetHits[N];

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "Enter number of hits for day %i: ", i + 1 );
        scanf ( "%i", &InternetHits[i] );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "Number of hits in day %i was %d\n", i + 1, InternetHits[i] );
    }
}
```

If it is indeed a C++ program then it can look like

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const int N = 10;
    int InternetHits[N];

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "Enter number of hits for day %i: ", i + 1 );
        scanf ( "%i", &InternetHits[i] );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf ( "Number of hits in day %i was %d\n", i + 1, InternetHits[i] );
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the only differences `<stdio.h>` and `<cstdio>` and that N 10 is in a different place?

Comment: @Bill  Usually C++ programs do not use C input/output functions. They use C++ streams. However as you are using printf in your program then I did not change it.